Finiteness of double integral involving conditional Gaussian density
Given that $\pi(W|V)$ and $\pi(W|V, Y)$ are both multivariate Gaussian distribution. $\pi(V|W)$ are some other proper density.
Does the finiteness of $$\int \int \pi(V|W) \pi(W|V) \, dW \, dV$$ implies the finiteness of
$$\int \int \pi(V|W) \pi(W|V,Y) \, dW \, dV$$
It feels like so since the tail of $\pi(W|V,Y)$ are slighter than the tail of $\pi(W|V)$. Or does it depends on the explicit form of $\pi(V|W)$ ?
